# Filter by several possible values in a single condition in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, boolean

Long story short, I want to perform a filter on column A (task ID) with several possible values of column B (assignees), but **I don't want to place those possible values in separate conditions** (in case I want to pass an array with the possible values for the filter). For example:

`FILTER(A2:A15, EXACT(B2:B15,J1)+EXACT(B2:B15,K1))`

Where J1 = "Jack" and K1 = "Jones". But if I merge the two conditions (because I have a lot of possible correct values):

`FILTER(A2:A15, EXACT(B2:B15,J1:K1))`

then Exact outputs a two dimensional boolean array which causes a **#VALUE** error on the filter operation stating **FILTER range must be a single row or a single column**.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with query

```
=query( A1:B,"select A where B matches '"&join("|",J1:K1)&"' ")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your answer worked, but I realized my question did not completely reflect my problem. I have updated the question accordingly. See now that while my condition is on column B, I want to retrieve the column A values.